# Get current week and date of week in react native

Tags: javascript, date, dayofweek, getdate

I need to display a whole week from Monday To Sunday in following format "Week 2: 05.01 - 11.01" as an example

```
let d = new Date();
let date = d.getDate();
let day = d.getDay();
let currentWeek = Math.ceil((date + 6 - day) / 7);
```

this is what i have for the current week, i know that it will have some issues if the previous month is in the first week of the current month.

Any help as to how to make it accurate and reliable?

***I need it to work in React Native!***

Comment: Are you wanting the week of the month, or week of the year?

Comment: @LonnieBest current week of the month :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's a option but I would rather gather a solution that is more reliable :) I know that i could get it to work with Date but suggestions like moment js could be more reliable

Comment: What is your algorithm for determining the week of the month?

Comment: I look forward to this [stage2 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal#overview--motivation).

Answer (score 0):

I like using moment to deal with Dates, since date operations are somewhat complex considering month changes, leap years and all that.

Using moment, you'd just need to do

```
const today = moment();
const begginingOfCurrentWeek = today.startOf('week');
const endOfWeek = today.endOf('week);
```

I havent tested it, but it should be something along those lines. You can also format dates easily using moment().format('DD/MM/YY'), for example.

Here's the link to their documentation:
https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Very interesting, might have to look into it, i am using react native but it has a libary support for react native so it might be the best solution for me

Comment: I use it with React Native too. It works alright :)

Comment: A more modern option would be [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/).

Comment: @LonnieBest for react native too?

Comment: @clockingClock : I'm not sure. I read about it [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/the-future-of-date-and-time-in-javascript-e1772c7976c).

Comment: Apparently it works with React Native, @clockingClock! I never heard about it though. Does it have any clear advantages, @Lonnie Best?